# Laravel Model - Want to check where (or) orWhere in DB::raw

Tags: mysql, laravel

> This is my model function now its working correctly, but i want to check where (or) orwhere. I Already try that but cant get the apt answer

```
public static function getPlacementCountByStatus(){
        $countStatus = DB::table('placements')->where('status','1')->select(DB::raw('count(joborderid) as total, joborderid'))->groupBy('joborderid')->get();
    return $countStatus;
    }
```

**I want to check something like this**

```
->where('statusid','=','3')->orWhere('statusid','=','4')->orWhere('stageid','=','4')->orWhere('stageid','=','8');
```

> **// i want to check this in my $countStatus something like and or condition in my db::raw query**

Comment: But it something like or condition.

Comment: do you have any `statusid` or `stageid` column in the `placements` table??

Comment: And what is the problem with that trail of where's ?

Comment: yeah i have statusid and stageid in my table. Note(I updated my question)

Comment: Amarnasan no mate i just want to learn the alternative method

Comment: You should keep away from raw sql as much as you can, though...

Comment: Amarnasan  For What Reason ? Please tell still i have to learn lot in sql, mysql and laravel model

Comment: using raw sql instead of ORMs creates opening to security issues such as sql injection

Comment: ORMs ? sorry to ask so many question i just want to know the clear answer

Comment: You are using a library called `eloquent` to access the database. ORMs allow you to use objects that are later translated to database's languages such as SQL. ORMs normally take care to format the generated SQL in a ways to avoid SQL injection

Comment: you can check these links: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent   |
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping   |
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learn further by google it. Anyway thanks again for your valuable comments

Comment: also try to find some app that can monitor the queries that are send to the database. it will help you understand what queries exactly `eloquent` runs

Comment: sure friend. _/\ _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [where()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping) closure:

```
$countStatus = DB::table('placements')->where(function($q){
                $q->where('statusid','=','3')->orWhere('statusid','=','4')->orWhere('stageid','=','4')->orWhere('stageid','=','8');
            })
           ->select(DB::raw('count(placementid) as total,statusid'))
           ->groupBy('statusid')->get();

 return $countStatus;
```

> `From the docs`
>   Sometimes you may need to create more advanced where clauses such as
>   `"where exists"` clauses or nested parameter groupings.

In your case, you need to use `where closure` as you are trying to `combine AND,OR` operation, means you are trying to `group your parameters` in a block. Here `closure` mainly does what a `parenthesis` does in a sql query.

Comment: can you please explain mate what is the use of this. where(function($q){ }). I just want to know

Comment: i would suggest you to go through the laravel official documentation as they provide the best explanation in my opinion

Comment: oh sure i follow your words